# tf tree changes over time

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, tf-tree

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a 3 wheel robot with a hokuyo lidar on it and today I noticed that the tf tree changes over time. By the word change, I mean that it starts:

*odom->base_footprint(--> l_wheel,r_wheel)->base_link-->caster_wheel, hokuyo*

and it changes to:

*odom->base_footprint->base_link---->l_wheel,r_wheel,caster_wheel,hokuyo*

and goes back again at the first tree and then
moves back to the other one as time goes by. There is also an intermediate state where the tree is like that;

*odom->base_footprint(->l_wheel)->base-link--->r_wheel,caster_wheel,hokuyo.*

Is this normal ? Or there is something wrong with my model ? And if yes, what could possibly cause that malfunction?

*EDITED:*

After using raultron's advice and using roswtf I got the following errors:

```
ERROR TF re-parenting contention:
 * reparenting of [r_wheel] to [base_footprint] by [/gazebo]
 * reparenting of [l_wheel] to [base_footprint] by [/gazebo]
 * reparenting of [l_wheel] to [base_link] by [/robot_state_publisher]
 * reparenting of [r_wheel] to [base_link] by [/robot_state_publisher]

ERROR TF multiple authority contention:
 * node [/gazebo] publishing transform [r_wheel] with parent [base_footprint] already published by node [/robot_state_publisher]
 * node [/gazebo] publishing transform [l_wheel] with parent [base_footprint] already published by node [/robot_state_publisher]
 * node [/robot_state_publisher] publishing transform [l_wheel] with parent [base_link] already published by node [/gazebo]
 * node [/robot_state_publisher] publishing transform [r_wheel] with parent [base_link] already published by node [/gazebo]
```

I use a robot_state_publisher node for the frames of my robot, and the gazebo node automatically broadcasts too, because I have a a differential_driver_controller plugin as a gazebo element at my urdf model as presented below:

```
  <gazebo>
   <plugin name="differential_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">

            <rosDebugLevel>Debug</rosDebugLevel>
            <publishWheelTF>True</publishWheelTF>
            <publishTF>1</publishTF>
            <publishWheelJointState>true</publishWheelJointState>
            <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
            <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
            <leftJoint>joint_l_wheel</leftJoint>
            <rightJoint>joint_r_wheel</rightJoint>
        <wheelSeparation>0.22</wheelSeparation>
            <wheelDiameter>0.16</wheelDiameter>
            <broadcastTF>1</broadcastTF>            
            <wheelTorque>30</wheelTorque>
        <commandTopic>/labrob/cmd_vel</commandTopic>
            <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame>
            <odometryTopic>/labrob/odom</odometryTopic>
            <robotBaseFrame>base_footprint</robotBaseFrame>
        <legacyMode>true</legacyMode>
            
   </plugin>
  </gazebo>
```

This plugin broacasts the connections to the wheels, which is something that the robot_state_publisher also does. I changed some parameters to that:

```
  <gazebo>
   <plugin name="differential_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">

            <rosDebugLevel>Debug</rosDebugLevel>
            <publishWheelTF>False</publishWheelTF>
            <publishWheelJointState>True</publishWheelJointState>
            <alwaysOn>True</alwaysOn>
            <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
            <leftJoint>joint_l_wheel</leftJoint>
            <rightJoint>joint_r_wheel</rightJoint>
        <wheelSeparation>0.22</wheelSeparation>
            <wheelDiameter>0.16</wheelDiameter>           
            <wheelTorque>30</wheelTorque>
        <commandTopic>/labrob/cmd_vel</commandTopic>
            <robotBaseFrame>base_link</robotBaseFrame>
        <legacyMode>true</legacyMode>
            
   </plugin>
  </gazebo>
```

And now I have the following errors after roswtf:

```
Found 2 error(s).

ERROR TF re-parenting contention:
 * reparenting of [base_link] to [base_footprint] by [/robot_state_publisher]
 * reparenting of [base_link] to [odom] by [/gazebo]

ERROR TF multiple authority contention:
 * node [/robot_state_publisher] publishing transform [base_link] with parent [base_footprint] already published by node [/gazebo]
 * node [/gazebo] publishing transform [base_link] with parent [odom] already published by node [/robot_state_publisher]
```

Now I have two trees:

1. odom
2. base_footprint->base_link---->l_wheel,r_wheel,hokuyo_link,caster_wheel

**Any idea on how to get rid of that gazebo broadcaster?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241822/tf-tree-changes-over-time/) by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-08-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For me it looks like you have at least two different transform publishers publishing a TF to the same parent frame. Thats why you see different configurations of the three each time that you reload. Try to check which nodes are publishing transformations and try to disable them one by one until you don't see the changes on the tree anymore.

You can also use http://wiki.ros.org/roswtf to see if there is something weird.

Cheers

---

Originally posted by [raultron](https://answers.ros.org/users/48/raultron/) with karma: 61 on 2016-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2016-08-16**:
Hello and thank you for your answer. I re edited my question after using roswtf. Gazebo and state_publisher are broadcasting the same connections I guess. Any idea how to solve this and restrict the broadcasting to only one ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the answer after raultron's help.
I had to change the plugin to that:

```
  <gazebo>
   <plugin name="differential_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">

            <rosDebugLevel>Debug</rosDebugLevel>
            <publishWheelTF>False</publishWheelTF>
            <publishWheelJointState>True</publishWheelJointState>
            <alwaysOn>True</alwaysOn>
            <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
            <leftJoint>joint_l_wheel</leftJoint>
            <rightJoint>joint_r_wheel</rightJoint>
        <wheelSeparation>0.22</wheelSeparation>
            <wheelDiameter>0.16</wheelDiameter>
            <broadcastTF>0</broadcastTF>            
            <wheelTorque>30</wheelTorque>
        <commandTopic>/labrob/cmd_vel</commandTopic>
            <robotBaseFrame>base_footprint</robotBaseFrame>
        <legacyMode>true</legacyMode>
            
   </plugin>
  </gazebo>
```

And roswtf shows the tree without errors.

---

Originally posted by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) with karma: 354 on 2016-08-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raultron](https://answers.ros.org/users/48/raultron/) on 2016-08-17**:
I am glad you solved it :). Cheers.